# Task Management and Usage?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

So I got a server that shoots off the below task in a while loop it's functioning as my client listener. The issue seems like it wants to loop as fast as possible through the clients which is great! But it fires tasks off too fast before the previous task is done a new one happens ( for the same client).

I don't want it to wait for the task to complete! I want it to shoot more tasks but just not create anymore tasks for a specific client that already has an existing task.

What is the best way to go about this... I see a lot of people using WhenAll or something but I don't care about All the tasks.

```
//the below is in a while loop which goes through the clients that are connected.
  if (stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
// the below task is the one that is firing before the pervious fired one completes.
                         Task DataInterpetTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            int totalBuffer, totalRecieved = 0;
                            byte[] totalBufferByte = new byte[4];
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
                            byte[] tbuffer;
                            int rLength, prevLength;
                            stream.Read(totalBufferByte, 0, 4);
                            totalBuffer = BitConverter.ToInt32(totalBufferByte, 0);
                            Console.WriteLine("got stuff: " + totalBuffer);
                            byte[] buf = new byte[c.getClientSocket().ReceiveBufferSize];
                            while (totalBuffer > totalRecieved)
                            {

                                rLength = stream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                                totalRecieved = rLength + totalRecieved;
                                if (rLength < buf.Length)
                                {
                                    byte[] temp = new byte[rLength];
                                    Array.Copy(buf, temp, rLength);
                                    buf = temp;
                                }
                                prevLength = buffer.Length;
                                tbuffer = buffer;
                                buffer = new byte[buffer.Length + rLength];
                                Array.Copy(tbuffer, buffer, tbuffer.Length);
                                buf.CopyTo(buffer, prevLength);
                            }

                            String msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);
                            if (msg.Contains("PNG") || msg.Contains("RBG") || msg.Contains("HDR"))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Receiving Picture");
                                RowContainer tempContainer;
                                if ((tempContainer = MainWindow.mainWindow.RowExists(c)) != null)
                                {
                                    tempContainer.Image = buffer;
                                    Console.WriteLine("Updating row: " + tempContainer.rowNumber);
                                    MainWindow.mainWindowDispacter.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                        MainWindow.mainWindow.UpdateRowContainer(tempContainer, 0)));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Adding row for Picture");
                                    MainWindow.mainWindowDispacter.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                       MainWindow.mainWindow.CreateClientRowContainer(c, buffer)));
                                }
                                return;
                            }


                            String switchString = msg.Substring(0, 4);
                            if (msg.Length > 4)
                                msg = msg.Substring(4);
                            MainWindow.mainWindowDispacter.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                            {
                                if (MainWindow.debugWindow != null)
                                    MainWindow.debugWindow.LogTextBox.AppendText("Received message " + msg + " from client: " + c.getClientIp() + " as a " + switchString + " type" + Environment.NewLine);

                            }));
                            RowContainer tContain = MainWindow.mainWindow.RowExists(c);
                            if(tContain == null)
                                return;
                            switch (switchString)
                            {
                                case "pong":
                                    c.RespondedPong();
                                    break;
                                case "stat":
                                    tContain.SetState(msg);
                                    MainWindow.mainWindow.UpdateRowContainer(tContain, 1);
                                    break;
                                case "osif":
                                    tContain.Os = msg;
                                    MainWindow.mainWindowDispacter.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                       MainWindow.mainWindow.UpdateRowContainer(tContain, 2)));
                                    break;
                                case "idle":
                                    tContain.idle = msg;
                                    MainWindow.mainWindowDispacter.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                       MainWindow.mainWindow.UpdateRowContainer(tContain, 3)));
                                    break;
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to start a new operation for a given client until the previous one has completed, then just keep track of that. Either move the client object to some "in progress" list, so that it's not even in the list of clients that you are processing in your loop, or add a flag to the client object class that indicates that the operation is "in progress", so that your loop can ignore the client until the current operation has completed (e.g. `if (c.OperationInProgress) continue;`).

That said, it appears that you are using polling (i.e. checking `DataAvailable`) to manage your I/O. This is a really inefficient approach, and on top of that is the root cause of your current problem. If you were using the much better asynchronous model, your code would be more efficient *and* you wouldn't even have this problem, because the asynchronous API would provide all of the state management you need in order to avoid overlapping operations for a given client.

Unfortunately, your code example is very sparse, missing all of the detail that would be required to offer *specific* advice on how to change the implementation to use the asynchronous model (and what little code there is, includes a lot of extra code that would not be found in [a good code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). So hopefully the above is enough to get you on track to the right solution.